# ColdFusion 11 & IIS 7.5

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task registered in ColdFusion 11 Admin console. ColdFusion 11 is hosted over IIS 7.5. The schedule task is to run 1 perticular file from sub application of the main app. After remidiating all application from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11, scheduled task stopped working.

Note that, on IIS, main App has "Anonymous Authentication - Disabled" and "Windoes Authentication - Enabled" ...
While for sub app (which is being called by scheduled task) has "Anonymous Authentication - Enabled" and "Windoes Authentication - Disabled".

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't said what troubleshooting you've already done. Have you even looked at your logs?

Comment: When I run the scheduled task manually, it shows the following error:
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.